# I can't find bake option under cache while doing smoke simulation in blender 2.82

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was following a tutorial a youtube and my cache options are different than all people out there I don't know why. I also don't have a bake option in it. Here is a screen shot of my screen.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.82 under the *Cache* dropdown panel, set the *Type* to *Final*.

The bake button should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Render Engine** to 'Cycles':

[image]

Comment: Its already in cycles

Comment: That is not the right place to bake simulations, the image you show is to bake textures. it is a different process. The controls to bake simulations are in a different tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the render tab switch render engine to *Cycles* and then scroll down until you see a *Bake* dropdown menu. After that open the dropdown menu and there will be a *Bake* button.

Hopefully this helps.